# F# - what does match...with | :? X as x mean?

Tags: syntax, f#

Super simple question I'm sure but I don't do F# usually so a bit new to the syntax.

How do I read the following fragment of code:

```
        match shape.Fill with
          | :? PictureBrush as pb ->
              //....
```

Specifically, I'm not sure what `PictureBrush` refers to. There's not really any reference to it anywhere else in this file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This the [Type Test Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#type-test-pattern).

`PictureBrush` is a type. `shape.Fill` matches `:? PictureBrush` when the `Fill` property is assignable to that type.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that the `as` allows for binding of a variable to be of that type. So `pb` will be of type `PictureBrush`, but will have the exact same value as what `shape.Fill` resolved to.

Answer (score 1):

Its a type comparison.  Like typeof(xx) in C#. So match to type of PictureBrush.

Comment: I think it's more like [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.110).aspx).